# Are the two types equivalent in OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl

In the OpenGL xml specification, under the method glShaderSource, there is a parameter that is defined as `const GLchar *const* string`.

However on the [online registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glShaderSource.xhtml) for OpenGL, under the method glShaderSource, the same parameter is defined as `const GLchar **string`.

To my understanding the first is a pointer to an immutable pointer to an immutable character, and the second is a pointer to a pointer to an immutable character. To my understanding, this means that in the first definition, only the outermost pointer can be changed but in the second definition either pointer can be changed.

Are the two types equivalent, or is there an issue with the specifiacation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they the same thing? No. One is a constant array of strings, and the other is an array of strings.

This is not an issue with the "specification" (which agrees with the XML); this is a (minor) bug in the documentation.